# Open a TreeView without click

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a TreeView and into each register I have this button [image: button] to display the other items.

I want to know:
How can I open once I get node as

```
TreeNode grandpa = this.tvProjectList.Nodes[0];
```

How can I just open that specific `TreeNode`?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`TreeNode.Expand` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.expand(v=vs.110).aspx).

This behaves like the little cross [image] has been pressed.

Comment: I just try it but nothing happen, there is no another way to simulate right clic into that button?

Comment: @Rafael can you update your question and share exact code which you tried and details about what is happening and what do you expect?